# O que são esses Command e CommandHanlder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Vi em um projeto no github, de começo pensei que fosse uma forma de substituir os Dtos e os services, mas vi que ainda tem os services nesse projeto

alguém pode explicar o que é e como usar(se é bom usar ou não)

LINK:
https://github.com/robashton/RavenGallery/tree/master/RavenGallery.Core

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: poderia prover o link do  repositorio ou um exemplo do que está a questionar?

Comment: @MarcosBrinner esse aqui https://github.com/robashton/RavenGallery/tree/master/RavenGallery.Core tem varios outros no github que tem essas coisas, quer que eu atualize a pergunta e coloque alguns?

Answer (score 0):

Command e CommandHandler são objetos usados geralmente no padrão CQRS (command query responsibility segregation). É um padrão usado para fazer separação de consultas e commands(inserção e edição) no banco .

Dê uma olhada nesse link [https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs#:~:text=O%20CQRS%20significa%20Segrega%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de,a%20escalabilidade%20e%20a%20seguran%C3%A7a](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs#:%7E:text=O%20CQRS%20significa%20Segrega%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de,a%20escalabilidade%20e%20a%20seguran%C3%A7a).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).